# File contains a path separator.

Tags: android, file

When I try to check the existence of a particular file, I get `java.lang.illegalArgumentException: File contains a path separator`

What is the right way to do this using getFileStreamPath(..)?

```
File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("mnt/sdcard/photo/1342147146535.jpg");
   if(file.exists()){
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File exists in /mnt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

I also tried the following to replace the first line of the above codes. None of these worked.

```
File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("file:///mnt/sdcard/photo/aviary_1342147146535.jpg");
            File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("/mnt/sdcard/photo/1342147146535.jpg");
//          File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("mnt/sdcard/photo/1342147146535.jpg");
//          File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("file:///mnt/sdcard/photo/1342147146535.jpg");

            if(file.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File exists in /mnt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);}
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File NOT exists in /mnt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't make sense Context.getFileStreamPath trying to test wether a file path exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270098/i-cant-make-sense-context-getfilestreampath-trying-to-test-wether-a-file-path-e)

Comment: why not using `File file = new File("path");` and you are using file streaming? Despite that getFileStreamPath does not work that way as it is mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write below code for that.

```
File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("/mnt/sdcard/photo/1342147146535.jpg");
if(file.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File exists in /mnt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

And Follow below link for more detail.

[File Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253866/1466188)

Comment: getFileStreamPath() cannot accept filenames with file separators. You get an illegal argument exception.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I was trying with method getFileStreamPath. I think it takes file as parameter, not whole path; that's why it threw an exception. I solved with following method.

```
public static Boolean fileExist(Activity activity , String filePath) {
        String finalPath = activity.getFilesDir().toString() + File.separator + filePath;
        File file = new File(finalPath);
        return file.exists();
    }
```