# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/epay/share/Download/test280.mp4 cotains a path separator

Tags: android, file

I've also caught this problem, but not solved under your advise.  It's still prompt the same 
error:

as I've saw in

[File contains a path separator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467359/file-contains-a-path-separator?s=ed9e768e-ee6f-4d99-b2d2-6d53d62df5f8#new-answer)

The problem cause by :

```
if (isValidMediaFile && (dir != null) ) {
    boolean bFile = dir.exists();
    Log.i(TAG,"file flag " + bFile);
    if(!bFile){
        dir.mkdirs();
        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp " + f + " " + f);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "dir= " + dir.getPath());
    try {
        String file = 
                srcfile.substring(srcfile.lastIndexOf("/")+1, 
                        srcfile.length());
        File dstfile = new File(
                dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file);
        Log.i(TAG, "dst =" + dstfile);
        if(!dstfile.exists()){
            dstfile.createNewFile();
        }
        //copyFile(srcfile, dstfile);
        //FileInputStream in = context.openFileInput(srcfile);

        File sfile = context.getFileStreamPath(srcfile);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sfile);

        BufferedInputStream bi =  new BufferedInputStream(in);

        FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(dstfile.getName(), 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        byte[] b = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while( (len = bi.read(b))!= -1) {
            bo.write(b, 0,len);
        }
        out.flush();

        bi.close();
        bo.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();                    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
}
```

the log messages is :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/epay/share/Download/test280.mp4 cotains a path separator
at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1682)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getFileStreamPath(ContextImpl.java:541)

Comment: I've just wanna copy a file from /data/epay/share/Download/test280.mp4 from phone memory

to sdcard folder as /mnt/sdcard/video

Comment: "the log messages is..." should be "the log messages are..." sorry to check my grammar error  in natural language.

Comment: you can use FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile) from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29

Comment: new File("/data/epay/share/Download/test280.mp4");
and I have no FileUtils package, I do use copyFile(File srcfile, File dstfile) thus implements it by self.

Comment: you need to download http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: thank you.  
my copy file like this:

 public static void copyFile(File srcfile, File dstfile)
   throws IOException {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcfile);
  BufferedInputStream bi =  new BufferedInputStream(in);
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstfile);
  BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
  
  byte[] b = new byte[8192];
  int len;
  while( (len = bi.read(b))!= -1) {
   bo.write(b, 0,len);
  }
  out.flush();
  
  bi.close();
  bo.close();
  in.close();
  out.close();
 }

Comment: thank you. Raghunandan. The problem has resolved. :)