# An error occured while writing into a text file from Android app

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app and I would like to write into a text file. But after clicking the write button, the app shows me an error message and stops. The error is

> IllegalArgumentException: File mnt/sdcard/test.txt contains a path separator

I have used the following code:

```
try {
    final String TESTSTRING = new String("Hello Android");

    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("mnt/sdcard/test.txt",
                                               MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

    osw.write(TESTSTRING);

    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: could you provide us the error message?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: File mnt/sdcard/test.txt contains a path separator

Comment: please, check if these links can help you somehow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467359/file-contains-a-path-separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /`> in your manifest as well.

```
 package com.example.fileio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FilioActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;
    private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        CreateExternalLogFile("I am adding something into the text file!");
    }

private void CreateExternalLogFile(String s){
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
    tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+ dir);
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file,false); //True = Append to file, false = Overwrite
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);
        p.print(s);
        p.close();
        f.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                        " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    tv.append("\nFile written to \n"+file);


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try something like this      

       try {
         File myFile = new File("/sdcard/sample.txt");

         // added extra

         myFile.createNewFile(); 

         FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
         OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
         new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);    
         myOutWriter.close();
         fOut.close();
      }
```

dont forget add "`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`" in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not currently required. This isn't the problem.

The problem is that you're trying to a file with a path to private storage.

openFileOutput() opens a File for writing to your private area. The filename argument can't contain a path. The reference documentation says:
"The name of the file to open; can not contain path separators."
(see [reference doc for openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)). To write to internal storage, simply use openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE). No reason to set any other mode; your app is the only one that can access the file.

If you want to write to external storage, use [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29), specify the type of subdirectory (if you want to), and then use normal java.io.* objects (such as File) to write to the file. The reference documentation shows an example. Notice that files in external storage are visible to other apps.